# Pass JSON array to custom element in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular

I can't seem to pass a JSON array in a angular component (custom element). I have the code in which I loop through the JSON array, and I have the array data set up in `@Inject`. Example:

```
import {
  Input,
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  EventEmitter,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-wrapper',
  template: `
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items
        {{ item.title }}
        {{ item.age }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  @Input() items: any[];
}
```

Then, in my `index.html` file I call the `custom element` and I'm trying to pass a JSON array of objects into it, for example:

```
<custom-wrapper [items]="[{"title": "Mr", "age" : 23}, {"title": "Ms", "age" : "25"}]"></custom-wrapper>
```

All I get is an empty `<custom-wrapper [items]="[{"title": "Mr", "age" : 23}, {"title": "Ms", "age" : "25"}]"></custom-wrapper>` when I'm in inspect mode, and nothing is being listed.

Can someone help me locate the issue?

Comment: You have couple of issues in your code: 1) `<li *ngFor="let item of items">`; 2) Use `item.title` and `item.age`

Comment: Thanks for the note, edited the post. Tried that and still no luck. Is the actual passing of the data in the custom element fine?

Comment: @BlueBird03 Please choose an answer as accepted, if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass you're array using single quotes as you're using double quotes for attributes.

So this should be you're index.html:

```
<custom-wrapper [items]="[{title: 'Mr', age: 23}, {title: 'Ms', age: 25}]"></custom-wrapper>
```

Also in you're WrapperComponent, fix your `li` like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
```